# Invite members to board with Trello.NET

Tags: trello, trello.net

Is there a way to invite members to a board or even just assign them as admins/users via the API? I'm trying to automate our project request system so that when a new project is approved a new Trello board is created and my team is assigned as admins to the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented in Trello.NET. I added [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/issues/18) for this.

**Edit**: Implemented by @theyshookhands and on NuGet (version 0.5.8)

Comment: Yeah I saw it just now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty simply with [Manatee.Trello](https://nuget.org/packages/Manatee.Trello/)...