# Is there a way to use the Python API for Trello to invite members to a board?

Tags: python, api, addition, member, trello

When reviewing the abilities of the [Python API for Trello](https://pythonhosted.org/trello/trello.html) and considering its functionalities,
I was searching for a function that allows to add a member to a board - w./o. success.

What I have tried to use is the following:

```
trello = TrelloAPI(myAPIKey, myToken)
boardID = myBoardID
fields = {"fullName": "Robo Member",
          "email" : myMail}

trello.boards.get_membersInvited(board_id = boardID, 
                                   fields = fields)
```

This is how the method implementation looks like:

```
   def get_membersInvited(self, board_id, fields=None):
    resp = requests.get("https://trello.com/1/boards/%s/membersInvited" % 
    (board_id), params=dict(key=self._apikey, token=self._token, 
    fields=fields), data=None)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    return json.loads(resp.content)
```

I end up receiving 404 Client Error URL not found.
Do you have any suggestions on what to adjust?

Maybe, I used the wrong field names (email and fullName)?

Here is a [solution for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345104/invite-members-to-board-with-trello-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a remedy by myself. Source -->  [Trello API Board Put Member](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#boardsidlabelnamesmembers)

Here my own solution:

```
    def invite_new_member(self, fullName, email, boardID):
    url = self.baseURL + "boards/" + boardID + "/members"
    querystring = {"email": email, "key": apikey,
                   "token": token}
    payload = "{\"fullName\":\"" + fullName + "\"}"
    headers = {
        'type': "normal",
        'content-type': "application/json" }

    response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers, 
    params=querystring)
```